# __int8 does not name a type

Tags: c++

I'm following an exercises about MASM, and there is this exercises that has C++ and MASM code together.

I have the following C++ code:

```
// Interi con segno
typedef __int8  Int8;
typedef __int16 Int16;
typedef __int32 Int32;
typedef __int64 Int64;

// Interi senza segno
typedef unsigned __int8  Uint8;
typedef unsigned __int16 Uint16;
typedef unsigned __int32 Uint32;
typedef unsigned __int64 Uint64;
```

But when I try to compile it I get the following errors:

```
MiscDef.h:2:9: error: ‘__int8’ does not name a type
    2 | typedef __int8  Int8;
      |         ^~~~~~
MiscDef.h:3:9: error: ‘__int16’ does not name a type
    3 | typedef __int16 Int16;
      |         ^~~~~~~
MiscDef.h:4:9: error: ‘__int32’ does not name a type
    4 | typedef __int32 Int32;
      |         ^~~~~~~
MiscDef.h:5:9: error: ‘__int64’ does not name a type
    5 | typedef __int64 Int64;
      |         ^~~~~~~
MiscDef.h:8:26: error: expected initializer before ‘Uint8’
    8 | typedef unsigned __int8  Uint8;
      |                          ^~~~~
MiscDef.h:9:26: error: expected initializer before ‘Uint16’
    9 | typedef unsigned __int16 Uint16;
      |                          ^~~~~~
MiscDef.h:10:26: error: expected initializer before ‘Uint32’
   10 | typedef unsigned __int32 Uint32;
      |                          ^~~~~~
MiscDef.h:11:26: error: expected initializer before ‘Uint64’
   11 | typedef unsigned __int64 Uint64;
      |                          ^~~~~~
```

In the course I am doing, the teacher used this code in Visual Studio and compiled it without any problem, but I cannot compile it with "i686-w64-mingw32-g++".

Can you please explain to me how I can solve this issue?

I tried to use `__int8_t`, `__int16_t`, etc like this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

// Interi con segno
typedef __int8_t  Int8;
typedef __int16_t Int16;
typedef __int32_t Int32;
typedef __int64_t Int64;

// Interi senza segno
typedef __uint8_t  Uint8;
typedef __uint16_t Uint16;
typedef __uint32_t Uint32;
typedef __uint64_t Uint64;
```

But I get the same error.

Comment: Did you mean [std::int8_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)? For portability use the publically visible types required by the standard, not whatever compiler internal implementation details `__int8` is exposing.

Comment: `__int8` (and similar) are non-portable and specific to the Microsoft VC++ compiler (used by default in Visual Studio).

Comment: Thank you for your answers, so how can I solve this? Using std::int8_t doesn't works. Which header I need to add?

Comment: Check out `<cstdint>`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint

Comment: [`#include <cstdint>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint)